# Sparse Matrix as input to Hierarchical clustering in R

Tags: r, sparse-matrix

I have a question about clustering using a distance matrix, but sparse.

Is there a sparse distance object format that does not expand the matrix and can work with the sparse representation?

Currently I'm doing the following

```
# read sparse matrix
sparse <- readMM('sparse-matrix')
distance <- as.dist(sparse)
```

sparse-matrix is already the correct distance matrix, which has NA's for entries that are not connected.

```
>sparse
[1,] . . .
[2,] 1 . .
[3,] 1 . .

> as.dist(sparse)
1 2
2 1  
3 1 0
```

But converting it with as.dist fails with

> Error in asMethod(object) : negative length vectors are not allowed

Presumably, because it expands the matrix to a complete form. The matrix (NxN) size is N = 49281
This format is needed (dist object) by for example the hclust method

Similar Question without any answer [on the R help list](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/sparse-distance-object-td4634299.html)

Answer (score -5):

How would a distance matrix be sparse? There is a distance between each two objects, so it is actually a very dense matrix. However, a triangular matrix is sufficient to describe the mutual distances (as **D** = **D**'). This is actually the case for the objects produced by `dist`.

If the distance matrix is sparse because lots of objects are the same, then maybe you'd want to calculate the distance matrix only on unique objects.

Comment: Okay, let's rephrase. The vectors that make the matrix are not very connected. So lot's of entries in the distance matrix should be NA. But as.dist turns it into a triangle matrix. The dist matrix is precomputed and I'm "just" trying to use that ...

Comment: @Joey: I still probably don't get it. If you calculate the distance of one object with some feature being `NA` to another object, is there any possibility that this distance is *not* `NA`?

Comment: This applies, when you use for example the cosine distance and ignore values which are 1, eg orthogonal