# Is there any sparse support for dist function in R?

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, hierarchical-clustering

Have anyone heard about any package or functionality that works the same as the `dist{stats}` function from R which creates the

> distance matrix that is computed by using the specified distance measure to compute the distances between the rows of a data matrix,

but take a sprase matrix as an input?

My data.frame (named `dataCluster`) has dims: 7000 X 10000 and is almost 99% sparse. In regular form that is not sparse this function doesn't seem to stop working...

```
h1 <- hclust( dist( dataCluster ) , method = "complete" )
```

Similar question without an answer:
[Sparse Matrix as input to Hierarchical clustering in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15911022/sparse-matrix-as-input-to-hierarchical-clustering-in-r)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want [`wordspace::dist.matrix`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/wordspace/versions/0.2-0/topics/dist.matrix).

It accepts sparse matrices from the `Matrix` package (which isn’t clear from the documentation) and can also do cross distances, output both `Matrix` and `dist` objects and more.

The default distance measure is `'cosine'` though, so be sure to specify `method = 'euclidean'` if you want that.

Comment: 2 years have passed since I've asked this question. Thanks for the answer! Now I would use the `cosine` distance, for sparse matrixes that probably represented document term matrixes which I wanted probably to cluster that day : )

Comment: Haha I know, but I thought it deserves the answer. Also, the package didn’t exist when you asked the question, so at least the two of us and the package author had the problem :D

Comment: `quanteda::textstat_dist()` also takes sparse matrices such as `dgCMatrix` from the `Matrix` package and returns a dist object.

Comment: @KoheiWatanabe `textstat_dist() only works on dfm objects.` =(

Answer (score 1):

**Update: ** You can do what qlcMatrix does quite easily in fact:

```
sparse.cos <- function(x, y = NULL, drop = TRUE){
    if(!is.null(y)){
        if(class(x) != "dgCMatrix" || class(y) != "dgCMatrix") stop ("class(x) or class(y) != dgCMatrix")
        if(drop == TRUE) colnames(x) <- rownames(x) <- colnames(y) <- rownames(y) <- NULL
        crossprod(
            tcrossprod(
                x, 
                Diagonal(x = as.vector(crossprod(x ^ 2, rep(1, x@Dim[1]))) ^ -0.5)
            ),
            tcrossprod(
                y, 
                Diagonal(x = as.vector(crossprod(y ^ 2, rep(1, x@Dim[1]))) ^ -0.5))
            )
        )
    } else {
        if(class(x) != "dgCMatrix") stop ("class(x) != dgCMatrix")
        if(drop == TRUE) colnames(x) <- rownames(X) <- NULL
        crossprod(
            tcrossprod(
                x,
                Diagonal(x = as.vector(crossprod(x ^ 2, rep(1, nrow(x)))) ^ -0.5))
        )
    }
}
```

I can find no significant difference in performance between the above and `qlcMatrix::cosSparse`.

---

`qlcMatrix::cosSparse` is faster than `wordspace::dist.matrix` when data is >50% sparse or the similarity is being calculated on the longest edge of the input matrix (i.e. tall format).

Performance of `wordspace::dist.matrix` vs. `qlcMatrix::cosSparse` on a wide matrix (1000 x 5000) of varying sparsity (10%, 50%, 90%, or 99% sparse) to calculate a 1000 x 1000 similarity:

```
# M1 is 10% sparse, M99 is 99% sparse
set.seed(123)
M10 <- rsparsematrix(5000, 1000, density = 1)
M50 <- rsparsematrix(5000, 1000, density = 0.5)
M90 <- rsparsematrix(5000, 1000, density = 0.1)
M99 <- rsparsematrix(5000, 1000, density = 0.01)
tM10 <- t(M10)
tM50 <- t(M50)
tM90 <- t(M90)
tM99 <- t(M99)
benchmark(
 "cosSparse: 10% sparse" = cosSparse(M10),
 "cosSparse: 50% sparse" = cosSparse(M50),
 "cosSparse: 90% sparse" = cosSparse(M90),
 "cosSparse: 99% sparse" = cosSparse(M99),
 "wordspace: 10% sparse" = dist.matrix(tM10, byrow = TRUE),
 "wordspace: 50% sparse" = dist.matrix(tM50, byrow = TRUE),
 "wordspace: 90% sparse" = dist.matrix(tM90, byrow = TRUE),
 "wordspace: 99% sparse" = dist.matrix(tM99, byrow = TRUE),
 replications = 2, columns = c("test", "elapsed", "relative"))
```

The two functions are quite comparable, with wordspace taking a slight lead at lower sparsity, but definitely not at high sparsity:

```
                   test elapsed relative
1 cosSparse: 10% sparse   15.83  527.667
2 cosSparse: 50% sparse    4.72  157.333
3 cosSparse: 90% sparse    0.31   10.333
4 cosSparse: 99% sparse    0.03    1.000
5 wordspace: 10% sparse   15.23  507.667
6 wordspace: 50% sparse    4.28  142.667
7 wordspace: 90% sparse    0.36   12.000
8 wordspace: 99% sparse    0.09    3.000
```

If we flip the calculation around to compute a 5000 x 5000 matrix, then:

```
benchmark(
 "cosSparse: 50% sparse" = cosSparse(tM50),
 "cosSparse: 90% sparse" = cosSparse(tM90),
 "cosSparse: 99% sparse" = cosSparse(tM99),
 "wordspace: 50% sparse" = dist.matrix(M50, byrow = TRUE),
 "wordspace: 90% sparse" = dist.matrix(M90, byrow = TRUE),
 "wordspace: 99% sparse" = dist.matrix(M99, byrow = TRUE),
 replications = 1, columns = c("test", "elapsed", "relative"))
```

Now the competitive advantage of cosSparse becomes very clear:

```
                   test elapsed relative
1 cosSparse: 50% sparse   10.58  151.143
2 cosSparse: 90% sparse    1.44   20.571
3 cosSparse: 99% sparse    0.07    1.000
4 wordspace: 50% sparse   11.41  163.000
5 wordspace: 90% sparse    2.39   34.143
6 wordspace: 99% sparse    0.64    9.143
```

The change in efficiency is not very dramatic at 50% sparsity, but at 90% sparsity, wordspace is 1.6x slower, and at 99% sparsity it's nearly 10x slower!

Compare this performance to a square matrix:

```
M50.square <- rsparsematrix(1000, 1000, density = 0.5)
tM50.square <- t(M50.square)
M90.square <- rsparsematrix(1000, 1000, density = 0.1)
tM90.square <- t(M90.square)

benchmark(
 "cosSparse: square, 50% sparse" = cosSparse(M50.square),
 "wordspace: square, 50% sparse" = dist.matrix(tM50.square, byrow = TRUE),
 "cosSparse: square, 90% sparse" = cosSparse(M90.square),
 "wordspace: square, 90% sparse" = dist.matrix(tM90.square, byrow = TRUE),
 replications = 5, columns = c("test", "elapsed", "relative"))
```

cosSparse is marginally faster at both 50% sparsity, and almost twice as fast at 90% sparsity!

```
                           test elapsed relative
1 cosSparse: square, 50% sparse    2.12    9.217
3 cosSparse: square, 90% sparse    0.23    1.000
2 wordspace: square, 50% sparse    2.15    9.348
4 wordspace: square, 90% sparse    0.40    1.739
```

Note that the `wordspace::dist.matrix` has more edge case checks than `qlcMatrix::cosSparse` and also permits parallelization through `openmp` in R. Also, `wordspace::dist.matrix` supports euclidean and jaccard distance measures, although these are far slower. There are a number of other handy features built into that package.

That said, if you only need cosine similarity, and your matrix is >50% sparse, and you're computing the tall way, `cosSparse` should be the tool of choice.